# Weird boolean behaviour : The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am baffled by the behavior of the following observation

```
>>> t = numpy.array([1,2,3])
>>> type(t)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> type(t) != numpy.ndarray
False
>>> type(t) == numpy.ndarray
True
>>> type(t) != numpy.ndarray or t == None
array([False, False, False])
>>> type(t) != numpy.ndarray or t != None
array([ True,  True,  True])
```

The last 2 statements seems to return a boolean list rather than just T/F from the other statements. Obviously if we want to test if the obj is a numpy array we will run into a ValueError due to the ambiguity.

**Why** does it behave like this ?

Comment: Should help with the confusion - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: `or` is lazy - if left side gives `True` then it doesn't check right side - so first `or` gives one `True` because left side gives `True`. And right side checks every element separatelly and give result for every element separatelly. You would have to use `any()` or `all()` - `any( t != None )` or `all( t != None )` - it depends on what you want to check.

Comment: It's not hurting you in this case, but be ware of including an array equality test in an `or` statement.  As you see `t==None` produces a boolean array.  `or` on the other hand is a Python scalar operator.  You'll the subject line error if that boolean array is on the LHS of the `or`.  It's not raised here because, as other explain, `or` is just returning that array, not using it in a test.

Answer (score 0):

`or` does not return a boolean, it returns *one of its operands*; so either the result of its left hand expression or of its right hand expression (whichever is *truthy* first). If your left hand expression is *falsey*, it evaluates and returns its right hand expression. And `t == None` on a numpy array returns an array of values.

All of these tests are bad practice though. Test for types using `isinstance`, and for equality to `None` use `is None`.